# Looking for a horror boardgame I used to play back in 1999 or so

Tags: identify-this-game, kids

Back when I was a kid (which would've been at least 15 years ago, so around 1999 or so) there was a game I used to play that I would like to find again.

This "horror" game took place in an haunted mansion or castle divided in four big rooms and multiple floors. Players can choose from different characters (and if I remember correctly, one of them was a dog) and advance through an high number of tiles by spinning a wheel. Some tiles had special effects on gameplay written on them, as "stop for a turn" or "go to tile number ###" and so on.

It was not "Ghost Castle" and not something about Scooby-Doo (the characters where anonymous). It was built in thick paper or cardboard (everything but the wheel was made in this material), and it wasn't a box but a book which become a 3D setting when opened.

It was none of those listed below, because this are way to small:

- Which Witch
- Haunted House
- Haunted Mansion
- Ghost Castle

Thanks!

Comment: Were you a kid 6 years ago? [Escape from the Haunted Mansion](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/390683/escape-from-the-haunted-mansion)

Comment: Nope, I was not a kid and it was not Escape From the haunted mansion, it's even bigger. Btw, now I'm 25 so it's been at least 15 years since last play...

Comment: [Relic Raiders: Haunted Ruins](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/38197/relic-raiders-haunted-ruins) looks like the game - it is 3d pop up, and has four rooms. Problem is it was released in 2008. Perhaps it's based on an older original?

Comment: As you said, it's not relic Raiders, but This is an interesting thread to follow, thanks!

Comment: 13 Dead End Drive? - http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1899/13-dead-end-drive

Comment: Nope, not 13 Dead end drive...  It is too small, also the four rooms are separated by wall, like an xy coordinate system where walls are the axes and rooms are the plain space... I'm sorry, it's difficult to describe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! It's name is "Ghost Hunters!" by Brian Lee and it's not a board game but a book, published for the first time in UK by Tango Books in 1998.

ISBN (for Italian edition) is 88-450-7851-5, and you can see it online at http://www.lafeltrinelli.it/products/9788845107351/Gioca_con_gli_acchiappafantasmi/Lee_Brian.html

Answer (score 1):

It is called 'Horror House'

I used to have it 3 dimensional board game with moving party and divided in to four large rooms, something used to roll down the stairs as I recall ad knock you over if you happened to be on that section.

Comment: Is it [this game on board game geek?](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17754/horror-house)

Answer (score 0):

TSR's "Nightmare House" by David marshal. No spinner but a power wheel. Haunted mansion & astral plane combat against an evil entity. A great game!  See:https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3535/nightmare-house

Comment: The "check mark" next to the top answer can only be given by the OP, so I think it's safe to say that the game has been identified as *Ghost Hunters*